# Where are the image files for the software logos kept?

Tags: files, icons, paths

I'm looking for the image file where the logo for Vim is stored on my system. When I go to my bin, I can find "links to shared libraries".

I run

```
whereis vim
```

And I can find one of the paths it lists is in

```
/usr/share/vim
```

I tried searching using the find command for file extensions .png, .jpg, .jpeg, but I could not find anything in that directory. Does anyone know where I can find the file? Even knowing the file type of the logo file might help me (assuming I have correctly identified the directory in which it is located).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the list of files in the package.

For example, https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/all/vim-common/filelist

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gvim.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/gvim.svg
/usr/share/icons/locolor/16x16/apps/gvim.png
/usr/share/icons/locolor/32x32/apps/gvim.png
```